# How to read a txt file containing about 2000 lines of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm trying to read a txt file containing about 2000 lines of `Tuples`, each line containing a `Tuple`.

Here are the first 10 lines from "data.txt".

```
(16, 21, 24, 42, 49)
(2, 12, 40, 42, 45)
(6, 19, 22, 36, 48)
(2, 5, 20, 24, 33)
(8, 12, 24, 28, 44)
(3, 15, 29, 30, 37)
(6, 17, 30, 33, 43)
(3, 15, 16, 29, 42)
(17, 18, 20, 35, 39)
(20, 21, 23, 43, 48)
```

I have successfully copied the entire lines of `Tuple` into a `List`, but it is stored as a `List` of `String` by default by Python.

Here's the output:

```
['(16, 21, 24, 42, 49)', '(2, 12, 40, 42, 45)', '(6, 19, 22, 36, 48)', '(2, 5, 20, 24, 33)', '(8, 12, 24, 28, 44)', '(3, 15, 29, 30, 37)', '(6, 17, 30, 33, 43)', '(3, 15, 16, 29, 42)', '(17, 18, 20, 35, 39)', '(20, 21, 23, 43, 48)']
```

How do I convert this `List` of `String` into a `List` of `Tuples`. Because I want to compare each index of a tuple to entire `List` of tuples, so that, if the value of index matches, I want the line number at which the index of the `Tuples` matches as an output. So, if I take second tuple from the "data.txt" i.e (2, 12, 40, 42, 45) , I need to compare it starting with next `Tuple` in the list [i.e (6, 19, 22, 36, 48)] to the entire `List` of `Tuples`.

For example:

If I take 2nd Tuple (2, 12, 40, 42, 45), I need to find at which line the number '2' appears in the same index in the rest of the `List` of `Tuples`. The number '2' appears next in line no. 4 and for number '12' it is in line no. 5.

My code for copying contents of "data.txt" to List. I haven't gotten to the comparing part yet. It'll much helpful if you suggest some methods to compare the `Tuples` as mentioned above as well.

```
with open('Data.txt', 'r+') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
data = []
for line in lines:
    data.append(line.strip())
print(data[:11])  # Printing only first 10  lines from 1999 lines
print(f"Number of tuples = {len(data)}")
```

Comment: You could use `ast.literal_eval` on each tuple.

Comment: Inside your loop instead of `data.append(line.strip())` just do `data.append(ast.literal_eval(line))` - you shouldn't even need the `.strip()`

Comment: BTW, please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to intend when i pasted the code.

Comment: @alani I replaced data.append(line.strip()) to data.append(ast.literal_eval(line)), your right i copied exactly what's in the txt file to the list. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the tuples using ast's [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```py
from ast import literal_eval

lines = []
with open('Data.txt', 'r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        data_tuple = literal_eval(line)
        lines.append(data_tuple)
```

Comment: It's called `literal_eval`, not `eval_literal`

Comment: And also you are only reading one line from the file - the OP's `for` loop is still required.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, left off the loop. But not OPs loop, there is no need to read the whole file at once

Comment: Following your edit, you are now reading in a single line and looping over *characters* - okay now corrected

Comment: @PedroRodrigues It is not the same as `eval` - it specifically avoids dangerous stuff.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues not any string, only literals.

Comment: @Dan I didn't know  we can loop through the txt file directly without reading, thank you works perfectly

Comment: can anyone explain what this literal_eval do and how it is different what i've done in my code p.s I very new to coding    Thank you

Comment: You appended a string so `"(1, 2, 3)"` but you wanted a tuple i.e. `(1, 2, 3)` (notice no quotes). `literal_eval` parses strings and returns python objects so long as they are literals (listed in the doc I've linked to in the answer). So it converts the string to a tuple for you.